# Is there a way to build an already-existing JavaFX app jar into a native application using GraalVM's Native Image?

Tags: java, javafx, graalvm-native-image

#### Overview

I have a JavaFX application (a mix of pure Java and B4J) that is compiled with JDK 19 into a jar. I would like to be able to package this application into a native executable. GraalVM's Native Image seemed like a promising option. I succeeded with the CLI version of this app. However, with the JavaFX version, I can't get `native-image` to find the JavaFX modules and the build fails.

I am doing this on Windows but my eventual goal is to build executables for Windows and Linux. I've already succeeded in doing so for the CLI version of my app.

I am using GraalVM 22.3.1.

#### Details

Running the JavaFX app like this works:

```
java --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%\javafx\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.swing,javafx.web,javafx.fxml,javafx.swt --add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.canvas=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom.transform=ALL-UNNAMED -jar MyApp.jar
```

The GraalVM Native Image documentation suggests that I should be able to adapt the above command to run with `native-image` like so:

```
native-image --verbose --module-path "%MODULE_PATH%" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.swing,javafx.web,javafx.fxml,javafx.swt --add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.canvas=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom.transform=ALL-UNNAMED -jar MyApp.jar
```

I've tried this where `MODULE_PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\javafx\lib` and where `MODULE_PATH` equals a comma-separated list of the full path to all the contents (`javafx.base.jar`, etc...) of that directory. In both cases, `native-image`'s verbose logs report that `-imagemp` contains the value of the `MODULE_PATH`. The verbose logs report `-imagemp` as distinct from `-module-path` leading me to believe the former is the module path for the image being generated and the latter is the module path for the JVM instance running `native-image`. However, for both values of `MODULE_PATH`, it aborts with

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.swt not found
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage$NativeImageError: Image build request failed with exit status 1
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.showError(NativeImage.java:1730)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.build(NativeImage.java:1427)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.performBuild(NativeImage.java:1387)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.main(NativeImage.java:1374)
```

I tried removing javafx.swt from the added modules. `native-image` then fails while mentioning its inability to find another javafx module, leading me to believe that `native-image` is not finding *any* of the javafx modules.

Is there a way to get this to work? Or an alternative?

- I've looked at Gluon's GraalVM solution but their GraalVM download has JDK 17 in it. I need JDK 19. It also looks like it's designed for projects that are started from scratch, not for an already existing jar.
- I've also looked at putting the module-path in the jar's MANIFEST.MF. However it seems only Class-Path is supported. And I'm not sure this would fix anything since `native-image` is correctly receiving the module path info from the command line. It's just not able to use it to find the javafx modules.

Comment: You could use the official GraalVM 22.3.0 (JDK 19) with the GluonFX plugin, and you could create just an empty project with your jar as a dependency and a main that simply calls your application class.

Comment: Looks like the Gluon Eclipse plugin has been delisted from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Info on [GraalVM and JavaFX from gluon](https://gluonhq.com/create-native-javafx-applications-using-graalvm-22-builds-from-gluon/).

Comment: You can generate a project template from here as well: https://start.gluon.io